# Need a help Flet-Python centering my entries

Tags: python, sorting, alignment, flet

Hello guys its my first question here, :D
iam new learner on python and iam trying to make my second project using Flet
on this project iam trying to make a website so i started with looking into Flet Documentation
and i made this code

```
from flet import *
from views import views_handler

def main(page: Page):
  page.title = "Home"
  page.window_height=500
  page.window_width=500
  page.vertical_alignment= MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
  page.window_height= CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
  page.theme_mode = ThemeMode.DARK


  def route_change(route):
    page.views.clear()
    page.views.append(
      views_handler(page)[page.route]
    )


  page.on_route_change = route_change
  page.go('/')



app(target=main)
```

and i made view.py code too and Pages folder and the problem is that i cant center any button for any page

Here the code  for my SignUP.py

```
from flet import *
from flet import TextField, Checkbox, ElevatedButton, Text,Row,Column
from flet_core.control_event import ControlEvent


class Signuppage(UserControl):
    def __init__(self, page):
        super().__init__()
        self.page = page

    def build(self):
        self.page.title = "Signup"
        self.page.vertical_alignment = MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
        self.page.horizontal_alignment = CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

        self.username_signup: TextField =TextField(label="Username", width=200)
        self.password_signup : TextField =TextField(label="Password", width=200, password=True)
        self.checkbutton : Checkbox= Checkbox(label="I accept ", value=False)
        self.signup_button : ElevatedButton= ElevatedButton(text="Sign up", width=200, disabled=True)

        self.username_signup.on_change = self.validate
        self.password_signup.on_change = self.validate
        self.checkbutton.on_change = self.validate
        self.signup_button.on_click = self.submit

        return Column(
            controls=[Container(
                content=Column(
                    controls=[self.username_signup, self.password_signup, self.checkbutton, self.signup_button]),
                height=400,
                width=400,
                border_radius= 50,
                bgcolor=colors.GREEN,
            ),
            ],
        )

    def validate(self, e: ControlEvent) -> None:
        if all([self.username_signup.value, self.password_signup.value,self.checkbutton.value]):
            self.signup_button.disabled = False
        else:
            self.signup_button.disabled = True
        self.update()

    def submit(self, e: ControlEvent) -> None:
        print(self.username_signup.value, self.password_signup.value)
```

i tried to look at some examples on flet documentation and tried to apply them my code but it didnt whatever i try to do it dosent move from Left the only thing that made it kidna work is setting margin to 30

i would be happy if someone can help me learing and slove this and give me information about why its not changing

Answer (score 0):

first set the same width in this checkbox than in the Text Fields, `self.checkbutton : Checkbox= Checkbox(label="I accept ",width=200 ,value=False)` then in the returned column add `alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER`